# YouTube API v3: how to get totalResults (pageInfo) by javascript and query?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to get totalResults by javascript and query by url to YouTube.
If I get 0 results I need to pass a variable to the current tpl file, otherwise another variable.

```
eg. q (query) = "galaxy s6"
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=... ..."
...
...
if (json.pageInfo.totalResults == 0) {var x = "no"}
else {var x = "yes"}
```

and then pass the x to the tpl.
Can you help me, please?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, i did on tpl

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
    {literal}
    <script>
    function keyWordsearch(){
            gapi.client.setApiKey('myapikey');
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                    makeRequest();
            });
    }
    function makeRequest() {
            var q = 'galaxy s6';
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                       q: q,
                    part: 'snippet',
                    type: 'video',
                    location: '45.465422,9.185924',
                    locationRadius: '100km'                 

            });
            request.execute(function(response) {
                    if(response.pageInfo.totalResults >= 1) {
                    var res = 'yes';
                    } else {
                    var res = 'no';
                    }
            });
    }
 </script>
 {/literal}
```

problem 1):
how to pass that **res** in order to access it on the same page?
is possible in an easy way or first I use jquery to populate a field (eg. div) and then I read that field?

problem 2):
if I read that field with jQuery, it can load a js script for the page,
depending on the res value?

problem 3):
is possible to directly load from that javascript the other needed javascript for the entire page instead of passing a variable?

can I do something like this... ..?

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
if(response.pageInfo.totalResults >= 1) {

        fileref.setAttribute("src", fileONE.js);
                        } else {
        fileref.setAttribute("src", fileTWO.js);
                        }
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

thanks